# Customcontrols for Word's Ribbonbar?

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, ribbon-control

Is it possible to create custom controls for the Ribbonbar?
For example: I need a ComboBox which executes a macro after every KeyUp event and changes the background color of the control.

AFAIK there is no background color property in the MS-CUSTOMUI Combobox and only a "onChange" event which only works when hitting Enter.

Looks like I need to create my own ComboBox. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to create custom controls for the Ribbon. There are certain aspects of the Ribbon design that Microsoft reserves for itself. It only offers what's available for Ribbon XML.